# How to selectively manage the props of child components from within a parent component?

Tags: reactjs, routes, switch-statement

Consider following components:

1)

```
import React from 'react';

const toolbar = (props) => (
  <header>   
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li style={{display: props.displayHome}}>Home</li>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>   
  </header>
);

export default toolbar;
```

2)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Toolbar from '../../components/Navigation/Toolbar/Toolbar';

class Layout extends Component {
  render() {   
    return (
      <div>
        <Toolbar displayHome={this.props.displayHome}/>
        <main>
          {this.props.children}
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

3)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from './hoc/Layout/Layout';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage/Homepage';
import CategoryPage from './containers/CategoryPage/CategoryPage';
import SingleMealPage from './containers/SingleMealPage/SingleMealPage';
import SearchPage from './containers/SearchPage/SearchPage';
import AboutUsPage from './components/AboutUs/AboutUsPage';
import ContactPage from './components/Contact/ContactPage';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/category" component={CategoryPage} />
            <Route path="/singleMeal" component={SingleMealPage} />
            <Route path="/searchResults" component={SearchPage} />
            <Route path="/aboutUs" component={AboutUsPage} />
            <Route path='/contact' component={ContactPage} />
            <Route path="/" component={Homepage} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I want to display "Home" tab on every page except on Homepage.

I can obviously do that by importing Toolbar component in every relevant component and then manage "displayHome" property individually, but is there a way to achieve this with the current setup?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way in your case is to check `(this.props.location.pathname !== '/')` in App component and pass the result to Layout

Another way is to wrap Toolbar call in routing

```
class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Toolbar displayHome={false} />} />
          <Route path="/*" component={() => <Toolbar displayHome={true} />} />
        </Switch>

        <main>
          {this.props.children}
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to React so forgive me if I'm doing something wrong, but the first option doesn't work for me. When I `console.log(this.props.location.pathname)` in App component I get "Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined". `console.log(this.props)` gives me an empty array. But the second option works like a charm! Thanks mate.

Comment: It seems quite strange, please be sure that you check it when breakpoint set at return statement inside render()... Because this way is a bit more natural i guess in your case

Comment: I managed to do it! As it turned out, I had to wrap App component with a withRouter to get the access to these props, which is strange, since I already wrapped it with a BrowserRouter in index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse. Right now, you have managed the components without state as stateless components. Now make a stateful component to say, when the Home to be rendered : (I Used react hooks as you already have a function component)

Use render props of route to pass props to component like this:

**Option 1 : Use render props**

```
const [needsHomeMenu, setNeedsHomeMenu] = useState(false); // you can use this.setState({needsHomeMenu: true}) to achieve.
.
.
.
<Toolbar displayHome={needsHomeMenu}/> //Toolbar depends on this state
.
.
// update state from within the component that propagates to Toolbar
<Route path="/category" render={() => (<CategoryPage doesNeedHome={setNeedsHomeMenu} />)} />
```

In **CategoryPage.js** , get the prop and on mount , `doesNeedHome(true)`

In **HomePage.js**, `doesNeedHome(false)`. Now , the state changes and updates the Toolbar props and home goes away.

---

**Option 2:**

Use router props to decide the path location instead of route render in Option 1.
In **CategoryPage.js** and **HomePage.js** , get the prop and on mount , `doesNeedHome(this.props.location.pathname==='/')` or `doesNeedHome(this.props.location.pathname==='/home')`

Rest state update is same as above.

Component needs to be refactored accordingly in diff files.